# How to change a status bar color in a Fragment page as Transparent in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, statusbar

Am using this in **`fragment`** page

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
                getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparant));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

and remove this **android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”** from **XML**

Comment: thanks it works...i have added android:fitsSystemWindows=”true” in the xml due to this i didnt get the transparent , After removing this i got it.

Comment: @chandan happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Create a **`Custom`** class

```
public class CommonStatusBarColor {


     public void StatusBarColor(Activity activity, String colorCode)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                Window window =activity.getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode));
            }

        }


}
```

Then Call in **`onCreateView`** section.

```
 CommonStatusBarColor commonStatusBarColorObj =new CommonStatusBarColor();
 commonStatusBarColorObj.StatusBarColor(getActivity(),"#00ffffff"); // set your color
```